# Import a merged df from python to pgadmin

Tags: python, pandas, pgadmin

Hey y'all I'm currently learning python and was tasked with, what's to me a challenging problem. I need to export a merged df from python to pg_admin. I've read several articles and blog posts but struggle to make sense of them. I have attempted but failed to export the df successfully. Below is my most recent attempt.

Please, do let me know what I'm doing right and wrong. If possible, explain it in layman's terms so I can understand and learn.

My background is in accounting, so the learning curve for me is steep.

Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2 as psy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import datacompy as dcpy

user = 'postgres'
password = ' '
ip = '127.0.0.1'
db = 'final_project'
dbtype = 'postgresql'
port = '5432'
connect = f'{dbtype}+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{ip}:{port}/{db}'
conn = create_engine(connect)

gj = pd.read_excel('in/final_project/gj.xlsx')
gj = gj.rename(columns = {'payment_date' : 'transaction_date'})

t = pd.read_sql_table('transactions', conn)

gjt = pd.merge(gj, t, on = ['transaction_id'])
gjt = gjt.rename(columns = {'transaction_amt' : 'transaction'})
gjt = gjt.groupby(by=['account', 'transaction_id'])[['transaction']].sum().reset_index()

print(gj.head())
print(t.head())
print(gjt.head())

gjt.to_sql('gjt_trial', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)
```

Comment: `pg_admin` is a UI to manage Postgres databases. There is no importing into it but rather importing into your PG database.

Comment: What is the error or undesired results you are facing? Please explain *failed to export the df*. This is akin to saying *my code does not work* with no further details. We cannot run your code without your pandas data (`gj.xlsx`) or Postgres database (`final_project`).